# Find all catchable exception for specific block in Intellij IDEA

Tags: java, exception, intellij-idea

I want to catch all possible exceptions in a specific block and handle every type of exception in a separate catch block. So I want to know, how I can find all cachable exceptions in an specific block in Intellij?
I know I can put a catch for *Exception* so that all exceptions will be caught. But as I told I want to handle every type of exception separately.

Comment: Doesn't IntelliJ automatically highlight every checked exception that might be thrown in your method body? That leaves unchecked exceptions but you generally shouldn't catch those. If you remove the `try` `catch` blocks, the IDE should automatically suggest one based on the contracts of the methods invoked in the given line.

Comment: @toniedzwiedz Intellij will highlight all checked exceptions; You're right. But I wanna know is there any way to find all unchecked exceptions that are catchable? For example, I need a hierarchy diagram In the Intellij that show me all threw an exception in a specific block and show their parents.